# expo/google fonts Does not work outside App.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am a newbie. I'm making a YouTube Clone using React-Native.In my project I'm trying to use custom google fonts via [expo/google](https://github.com/expo/google-fonts) and I'm following their example. I installed "balsamiq-sans" font using `npx expo install @expo-google-fonts/balsamiq-sans`. Imported in App.js and it works ! BUT, when I try to use it in Header.js (component) it does not work. The fonts does not change.
Here's what I'v done-
App.js file

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Home from './src/screens/Home'
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import { useFonts, BalsamiqSans_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/balsamiq-sans';


export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    BalsamiqSans_400Regular,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
  return (
    
    <View>
      <Home  />
      <Text style={{fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_400Regular"}}> This Works ! </Text>
    </View>
  );
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../components/Header';


export default function Home() {

  
  return (
    <View >
      <Header />
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

And finally, Header.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Entypo} from "@expo/vector-icons"
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Constant from 'expo-constants'


export default function Header() {

  return (
    <View style={{
      paddingTop:Constant.statusBarHeight,
      height: 80,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      flexDirection: "row",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
      elevation: 5
    }}>
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        margin: 5,
        padding: 5,
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
        <Entypo style={{
          marginLeft: 20
        }} name='youtube' size={24} color="red" />

        <Text style={{
          fontSize: 19,
          marginLeft: 10,
          fontWeight: "bold",
          fontFamily: "BalsamiqSans_400Regular"
        }}>Does not work</Text>                  // this does not work

      </View>
      <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row"
      }} >
      <Ionicons name="ios-search-circle" size={27} color="black" />
      <Ionicons style={{marginRight: 20, marginLeft: 20}} name="ios-sunny-sharp" size={25} color="black" />
      </View>
      
    </View>
  )
    }
```

Any ideas? what am I doing wrong. And sorry for bad English.
Edit: Fonts change in web but does not change in my Android emulator and in my Android Phone(using Expo Go)

Answer (score 0):

move this to header component

```
import { useFonts, BalsamiqSans_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/balsamiq-sans';


export default function Header() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    BalsamiqSans_400Regular,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
```

then read this [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts/#beyond-otf-and-ttf) to know what formats work on which platforms:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply, I'v tried loading the custom font in the header component however it does not work. Also I'm having this warning that says," AppLoading has been Deprecated" If that helps.

Comment: try other fonts from [this](https://directory.vercel.app) ,  and replace <AppLoading /> with [ActivityIndicator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/activityindicator/)